# How do you display all 3 navigators in a react native app?

Tags: react-native-navigation

I'm trying to achieve something like the following image, with a drawer navigator and tab navigator present on every screen in my app.

[Mobile app with all 3 navigators present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK7Gh.png)

As I understand it, every screen needs to be present in one of the 3 react native navigators for a navigator to handle the request to navigate to that screen. Drawer navigator and tab navigator both have the downside that listing every screen in my app wouldn't be a good user experience (as far as I know there's no way to contain screens in those navigators without them being visible in the drawer or bottom tab) so this leaves all the remaining screens to be included in a stack navigator.

Thus the only way I see of having those 2 UI elements + the functionality of navigating to additional screens is to nest all 3 navigators. Is that right? Am I not understanding something correctly?

I wrote a trivial example with 4 screens: hamburger, hot dog, fries, and condiments. The first 3 contain an image of their respective subject and can be navigated to from either the drawer or tab navigator. The condiment screen contains links to navigate to 4 more screens that are inaccessible from the drawer or tab navigator: ketchup, mustard, mayo and relish.

The way I structured the navigators was like so:

```
App.js
---TabNav
------DrawerNav
---------StackNav
```

The following is an excerpt from the app although without the other navigators it's not as useful. The complete example can be found on github [here](https://github.com/gusmccallum/navdemo).

Regardless, one point I'm not sure about - rather than writing a separate stack navigator for each stack screen to include as a component for each of the drawer screens I used the initialRouteName option to open a stack navigator with the appropriate entry point. Is this good form/is there something wrong with how I'm doing this?

```
import React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import StackNav from './StackNav';


const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const DrawerNav = ({ initialScreen}) => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator id="DrawerNav"
      initialRouteName={initialScreen}
      screenOptions={{
        headerTitle: "Gus' Restaurant",
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="HamburgerDrawer"> 
      {() => <StackNav initialScreen="HamburgerStack" />}
      </Drawer.Screen>
      <Drawer.Screen name="HotDogDrawer"> 
      {() => <StackNav initialScreen="HotDogStack" />}
      </Drawer.Screen>
      <Drawer.Screen name="FriesDrawer">
      {() => <StackNav initialScreen="FriesStack" />}
        </Drawer.Screen>
      <Drawer.Screen name="CondimentsDrawer"> 
      {() => <StackNav initialScreen="CondimentsStack" />}
      </Drawer.Screen>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  link: {
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  linkText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'blue',
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
  },
});

export default DrawerNav;
```

So my problems are:

1. Does nesting the navigators in this structure make sense? I'm finding it's prone to errors but it's the only structure that seemed to give me the ability to have both drawer and tab navigators present on every screen in my app while still allowing me to navigate to screen other than those contained in the drawer and tab navigator UIs.
2. I'm unable to show the same screen as "selected" in both the drawer and tab navigator - for example if I want to navigate to the hot dog screen, it will show as selected only in the navigator that got me there. Is there a way to truly navigate to the same screen from multiple navigators and have that represented visually?